# Get JSON format from MySql to javascript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, amcharts

i want to get the json format from my SQL database using PHP

here is a capture of mySql database

[image: capture from mySql database]

**data.php**

```
<?php  include("include/connexion.php");
$requete = "SELECT * from statistika";
$resultat = mysql_query( $requete ) or die( mysql_error() );
$rows = array(); 
$total_vue = 0;
```

here is the php code to get the data

```
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc( $resultat ) ) {
  $total_vue+=$data['temps'];
   $rows[] = array(
    "date" =>  strtotime( $data['date']) * 1000,
    "value" => $data[ 'temps' ]
  );
}
?>
```

**json_encode.php**

```
<?php
 include("data.php");
 echo  json_encode($rows);
?>
```

The content of json_encode is valid and i get the json format successfully

```
[{"date":1439769600000,"value":"5"},{"date":1439787600000,"value":"12"},{"date":1439806631000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439821320000,"value":"18"},{"date":1439919642000,"value":"6"},{"date":1439889752000,"value":"2"},{"date":1439893260000,"value":"20"},{"date":1439906400000,"value":"9"},{"date":1429308000000,"value":"15"},{"date":1421535600000,"value":"12"},{"date":1413583200000,"value":"18"},{"date":1405634400000,"value":"6"},{"date":1439828640000,"value":"14"},{"date":1439935200000,"value":"19"},{"date":1439863200000,"value":"12"},{"date":1439884800000,"value":"18"},{"date":1439917200000,"value":"26"},{"date":1439920800000,"value":"4"},{"date":1439904320000,"value":"0"},{"date":1439907420000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907428000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907434000,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907437000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907447000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907452000,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907459000,"value":"5"},{"date":1439907469000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907482000,"value":"10"},{"date":1439907507000,"value":"21"},{"date":1439907510000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907519000,"value":"7"},{"date":1439907526000,"value":"5"},{"date":1439907547000,"value":"18"},{"date":1439907557000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907560000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907576000,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907581000,"value":"3"},{"date":1418857200000,"value":"300"},{"date":1426633200000,"value":"450"},{"date":1434578400000,"value":"500"},{"date":1424214000000,"value":"600"}]
```

Now i want to pass the JSON format to javascript , i am using this code

```
var foo = {};
foo.toString = function () { return <?php echo json_encode($rows);?> };
document.write(foo.toString);
```

the problem is that when printing foo.toString i get this

```
function () { return [{"date":1439769600000,"value":"5"},{"date":1439787600000,"value":"12"},{"date":1439806631000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439821320000,"value":"18"},{"date":1439919642000,"value":"6"},{"date":1439889752000,"value":"2"},{"date":1439893260000,"value":"20"},{"date":1439906400000,"value":"9"},{"date":1429308000000,"value":"15"},{"date":1421535600000,"value":"12"},{"date":1413583200000,"value":"18"},{"date":1405634400000,"value":"6"},{"date":1439828640000,"value":"14"},{"date":1439935200000,"value":"19"},{"date":1439863200000,"value":"12"},{"date":1439884800000,"value":"18"},{"date":1439917200000,"value":"26"},{"date":1439920800000,"value":"4"},{"date":1439904320000,"value":"0"},{"date":1439907420000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907428000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907434000,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907437000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907447000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907452000,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907459000,"value":"5"},{"date":1439907469000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907482000,"value":"10"},{"date":1439907507000,"value":"21"},{"date":1439907510000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907519000,"value":"7"},{"date":1439907526000,"value":"5"},{"date":1439907547000,"value":"18"},{"date":1439907557000,"value":"8"},{"date":1439907560000,"value":"1"},{"date":1439907576000,"value":"3"},{"date":1439907581000,"value":"3"},{"date":1418857200000,"value":"300"},{"date":1426633200000,"value":"450"},{"date":1434578400000,"value":"500"},{"date":1424214000000,"value":"600"}]
```

**i don't want `function () { return` to appear  in the output !!!**

Any hints ?

thanks .

Comment: First of all, I advise you not to mix `javascript` and `php` code in one file. It is a terribly bad style. Otherwise, at one moment you will get some awful spagetti code. You'd better get this json data from an ajax call. Just divide and conquer, as they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line in your JS code

From

```
foo.toString = function () { return <?php echo json_encode($rows);?> };
```

To

```
foo.toString = '<?php echo json_encode($rows);?>';
```

Comment: thanks, i want actually to use the data with amcharts library ... have you used this library before ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = {};
foo.toString = function () { return <?php echo json_encode($rows);?> };
document.write(foo());
```

You are creating foo as function so call like this you will get only json.